# Database query in rails, save model as variable in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(This is probably an easy question, but I didn't find the right words to google my problem)

In my controller I have a query like this:

```
information = Event.where(name: 'xyz')
```

Which works fine. In this case, only the model "event" gets queried and not other models like "Blog" or "Post". Instead of writing every query, I just want to call a method, which could look like this:

```
def find_information (model, word)
  information = model.where(name: 'word')
end
```

So, if I write `find_information (Event, xyz)`, it should do:

```
information = Event.where(name: 'xyz')
```

or if I write find_information (Blog, xyz), it should do:

```
information = Blog.where(name: 'xyz')
```

I tried this:

```
model = Event

"#{model}".where(name: 'xyz')
```

But this throws an "undefined method `where' for "Event":String" error. How do I save the model in a variable? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to make user pass the model name, when making these kinds of queries, I suggest whitelisting them:

```
def find_information(klass_string, query)
  whitelisted_classes = %w(Event Blog Post)
  if whitelisted_classes.include?(klass_string)
    klass = klass_string.constantize
    result = klass.where(query)
  end
end
```

I know it is not fully what you asked for, so to answer your original question, if you pass a class as a variable then you can use it right away

```
klass = Event
klass.where(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making a query to the name attribute with the string `'word'`

```
  information = model.where(name: 'word')
```

You should query the argument with `word`.

```
def find_information (model, word)
  information = model.where(name: word)
end
```

This works for me.
Hope this help.